# Modeling a mass/spring scenario in polar coordinates

Tags: matlab, differential-equations

I've got two second order non-linear differential equations which I need to solve in order to model and plot the motion of a mass hanging on a spring which is swinging like a pendulum. They are here:

[image]

I'm using odeToVectorField to rewrite them as first order linear ODEs, then I call ode45 to solve the resulting system of equations. But when I plot the results, it gives me strange answers, like negative radius, etc.

Can anyone help me find where I've messed up my code? Thanks a lot!

My code is as follows:

```
global m R g B k %declare global variables to use them everywhere

m=1.0; %mass of ball [kg]
k=200; %  stiffness of the spring [N/m]
R=0.5; % unstretched length of the spring [m]
g=9.81; % acceleration due to the gravity [m/s^2]
B=0; % coefficient of air drag [kg/m]


syms r(t) f(t)
[V] = odeToVectorField(diff(r,2)== r*((diff(f,1))^2) + (g*cos(f))-(k*(r-R))-B*diff(r,1)*sqrt(diff(r,1)^2 +r^2*diff(f,1)^2),...
    diff(f,2)== ((g*sin(f)+2*diff(r,1)*diff(f,1))/-r)-B*diff(f,1)*sqrt(diff(r,1)^2 +r^2*diff(f,1)^2));

F = matlabFunction(V,'vars',{'t','Y'});

%define initial conditions:
theta_0=(70*pi/180); 
theta_dot_0=0; 
r_0= R + (m*g*cos(theta_0))/k ;
r_dot_0=0;

t_start=0; %start time
t_step=.01; % time step
t_final=5; % final time



%Solve that system of ODEs from [V]
[t , X]=ode45(F, t_start:t_step:t_final , [r_0;r_dot_0;theta_0;theta_dot_0]); 

figure(1)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,X(:,1),'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('t');ylabel('r','fontsize',12);
hold on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,X(:,2),'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('t');ylabel('r dot','fontsize',12);
hold on

figure(2)
subplot(2,1,1)
plot(t,X(:,3),'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('t');ylabel('theta [rad]','fontsize',12);
hold on
subplot(2,1,2)
plot(t,X(:,4),'LineWidth',2)
xlabel('t');ylabel('theta dot [rad/s]','fontsize',12);
hold on
```

Comment: I see that your odeToVectorField does not correspond to your system of odes. Can you check that?

Comment: @ysakmoto Ah, yes you are correct. The system of ODEs in the image in my post is wrong, what is written in odeToVectorField is correct. I'll try to get a new image of the correct ODEs here in a minute. Thanks.

Comment: One way to verify your answer is to put your solution back to your ode system and see if it works.